# Electron remote error after bundling with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron

I'm making an Electron application with help of React, but after importing Electron's remote module I'm keep getting the following error after bundling the code with webpack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: r.existsSync is not a function
```

The code goes as following:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import * as path from 'path'
import {remote} from 'electron'

import Application from './components/Application'

const appRoot = document.getElementById('app-root')

console.log(remote.getGlobal('mainRoot'))

ReactDOM.render(
  <Application />,
  appRoot
)
```

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './templates/js/test.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'templates/dist'),
    filename: 'test.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }, {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your webpack config?

Comment: I forgot to add it, now it's there aswell.

Comment: I've resolved it by adding electron in externals in webpack config

Comment: You can also specify target as electron or electron renderer.

Comment: See https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/